# Identifying the logic gate needed for this problem

Tags: logic-gates

[Problem:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8L92t.png)

> **4  Q20.**   Sensors are used to monitor the pressure, volume, and temperature of a chemical solution stored in a vat.
>
> The circuitry for each sensor produces a HIGH voltage when a specified maximum value is exceeded. An alarm requiring a LOW voltage input must be activated when either the pressure, temperature or volume is too high.
>
> The vat sensor consists of a single logic gate whose inputs are connected to the pressure, temperature and volume sensors (one sensor per input), and whose output is connected to the alarm.
>
> What type of logic gate is needed to implement the vat monitor?

The solution to this problem states that the required gate is a NAND gate. I found it to be a NOR gate.

My reasoning was that since any 1 (input) was cause for the alarm to activate (needed a LOW), a NOR gate was required. Clarification is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely a 3-input NOR gate.

```
P V T A
0 0 0 1
1 X X 0
X 1 X 0
X X 1 0
```

Comment: I knew it... the solution is wrong. It stated "It must be a NAND gate.". Ridiculous.